# Leverage Angular controllers with JSP loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am pretty new to Angular.

Let's say I am using `c:forEach` to print a server-side generated content using JSP, like a list of fields.

Now I need to create a button where those fields will be added dinamically with javascript by the user (following the same template as the fields already printed from the server).

I am thinking of using angular to keep track of model changes instead of using plain jQuery, but I am having problems to use it with JSP.

My goal is to avoid angular to create the initial loop and to make it deal only with dynamic content manipulation after the HTML was generated by the application.

Is there a way to print a list of items using regular server-side language and then add angular just for the dinamic manipulation?

The example below would be the final HTML:

```
<ul class="container">

    <!-- Here is a initial server-side content generated from application output -->
    <li>Server generated Content</li>

    <!-- Here is a initial server-side content generated from application output -->
    <li>Server generated Content2</li>

</ul>
<!-- Clicking here add a new item inside ".container", it should be controlled by angular but I can't find a good pattern to do it -->
<button>Add new list element</button>
```

By the way, am I using angular in the correct way?

EDIT:
I don't want to generate again the same content using JSON format, I want to leverage angular and the regular HTML markup. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "angular way" of doing things does not account with server-side code generation, you should use REST or templates instead. Angular JS remove the burden of page loading or HTML manipulation from the server side and brings it to the front-end.

It is possible though to use server-side HTML generation and Angular JS using controllers and manipulating only a given portion of your page. If you are wondering about SEO keep in mind that Angular JS is not that friendly, other techniques should be used to deal with that case.

AngularJS is pretty useful for the internals of an application where SEO is irrelevant. In other hand, the public pages like the index should be simple and SEO friendly if your business require so.

**Short answer:** Angular does not work the way you supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="myModel" value="[{k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2'}]"/>
```

where value is set on server side and it is in JSON format. Then:

```
<input type='button' ng-click='addElement()' value='Add new Element'/>
```

And define `addElement()` method in your angular controller, something like:

```
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.addElement = function(){
      $scope.myModel.push({k3: 'v3'});
   }
}
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want to generate again the same content using JSON format, I want to leverage angular and the regular HTML markup.